# Why my javascript game is slow when compiled with nw.js (node-webkit)?

Tags: javascript, performance, compilation, executable, nw.js

It is not much slower than in a browser, but I thought it will be MUCH MUCH faster, since it is a native windows application when compiled, and not HTML5 app.

What am I missing?

It is graphic intensive game, lots of re-flows and re-paints, but that shouldn't be a problem for a native .exe app.

Comment: nw.js doesn't give you a raw executable, it just seems that way. It's still running JS using the V8 engine. But without any code highlighting slow spots, we can't help you. Do some profiling, figure out which sections are the slowest, and optimize those.

Answer (score 0):

Try with disabled disk caches to see if it helps the speed...

```
  "chromium-args": "--disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache --disk-cache-dir=W:/abc --media-cache-dir=W:/abc --disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1",
```

Take note that node webkit is just a "shell" that passes a script file to Chromium so it's not a native Windows prog.